# How to enable HTTPS together with debug in play framework 2.2.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using the play framework in version 2.2.3. I can configure play to use HTTPS and specify the port like described in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps). If I use the  `./nameOfMyApp -Dhttps.port=9443` it works just fine, but I can't debug in this mode.

If I look in the old [documentation of play 1.2.5](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/production) it says it's possible to specify the ports in the application.conf like:

```
http.port=9000
https.port=9443
```

But if I do this in 2.2.3 it just seems to be ignored. After running `play debug run` in my app's directory I just get

> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000 ...

Any ideas?

Really nobody?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this way:

```
activator run -Dhttps.port=9443
```